# Put \ref{} within \aaalphanum

Tags: hyperref

I'm trying to ref a label using \ref and output an alphabetical letter (e.g. 'A') rather than the number (e.g. 1).

I have read somewhere to use \AAAlphanum{\ref{my_label}} but this command fails

Missing number, treated as zero.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ the close voter: please give the OP time to make the question more clear before voting to close and if you're really going to vote to close this early, at least live a comment suggesting how the question could be improved/clarified.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways you can achieve this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{zref,refcount,alphalph,hyperref}

\makeatletter
\zref@newprop{AlphAlphcntr}[??]{\AlphAlph{\value{section}}}
\newcommand{\mylabel}[1]{\zref@labelbyprops{#1}{AlphAlphcntr}}
\newcommand{\myref}[1]{\zref@refused{#1}\zref@extract{#1}{AlphAlphcntr}}
\makeatother

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

\section{A section}\label{sec:mysection}\mylabel{sec:mysection}
Section~\ref{sec:mysection}. \par
Section~\AlphAlph{\getrefnumber{sec:mysection}}. \par
Section~\myref{sec:mysection}.

\end{document}
```

The first reference uses `\ref`, which defaults to whatever the `\the<counter>` is set to (in this case, `\arabic{section}`). The second reference uses the expandable `\getrefnumber` provided by [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount). The last reference uses a custom property list (with the aid of [`zref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/zref)) to only store and/or retrieve the `\AlphAlph`-version of the `section` counter.

All of the above can be extended to use [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), of course.